# SAS token using Azure AD Service Principle for ADLS Gen2 at directory level in java

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-sas, azure-spring-boot

I have been trying to get a SAS token for ADLS Gen2 using java but haven't got any good example or document, Can anyone please provide an example or document to follow. (I am able to generate for blob storage at container level but not for ADLS Gen2 at directory level)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [`azure-storage-file-datalake`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-datalake) library?

Since version `12.3.0` it supports Directory scoped SAS tokens, try `DataLakeDirectoryClient#generateSas()`.

```
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = dataLakeServiceClient
    .getFileSystemClient("fileSystemName")
    .getDirectoryClient("path/to/directory");

var startTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
var permissions = new PathSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
var values = new DataLakeServiceSasSignatureValues(startTime.plusDays(1),permissions)
    .setStartTime(startTime);

directoryClient.generateSas(values);
```